# How to sand/smooth a small plastic stylus tip?

Tags: sanding, plastic

I bought some cheap replacement styluses for a gadget with a plastic pressure-sensitive screen (a Wii U gamepad). Being cheap, the seams between the styluses' plastic halves are not well sanded, and the tips have varying degrees of scratchy protrusions that might damage the gadget's screen.

[image: Said stylus.]

What's the best way for me to smooth them down myself? Just a certain kind and grit(s) of sandpaper? If so, what kind/grit? If not, what else? I am extremely beginner level with this sort of thing, so you probably shouldn't assume I know even basic facts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a cheap replacement stylus for a gadget, not home improvement.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even stop to consider that. All I saw was, *How do I remove the parting line from something made out of plastic?*. I don't think it'd have been closed if it asked about removing them from the handle of your hammer... Replace *stylus* with *tool* and I'd say we're a go. I've applied my advice below to lots of my tools. If you use sand paper, you'll wish you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Plastic doesn't sand well. I'd CAREFULLY use an exacto knife on the parting line. Then polish it mechanically. Don't use turtle wax or anything like that; just rub it aggressively on some cloth. I.e., your jeans.

For me, my lighter makes a good backstop while in my fifth pocket, you might want to lay the cloth on a hard surface or you probably won't be doing it aggressively enough to do anything.

Comment: Also, just to add on to this.. If you are worried about ruining an expensive piece of tech because of a cheap item, I'd suggest just getting a higher quality stylus; they don't really ever cost much.

Comment: Agreed, sutures (stitches) aren't cheap either.